# Laravel Valet - CORS Issue in Mac

Tags: nginx, laravel-valet

I am using laravel valet for virtual host: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet in my mac

And i have linked the project and its working fine.

But, when I have called an API from frontend (React) App, it throws CORS issue.

I have already installed [laravel-fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) in my laravel project.

when i have stopped the `valet stop` and run apache2 service separately `sudo apachectl start` using `httpd`, and set a `httpd-vhost` with  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`, its working

But i can't able to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` for `valet`

Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

Note: I have tried to change the config from this answer (https://gist.github.com/poul-kg/b669a76fc27afcc31012aa0b0e34f738) But its not working either.

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this? Having the same issue!

Comment: Me too! Any resolution?